# Ascending probabilities with descending numbers

Tags: c++

I would like to write code which gives cumulative probabilities (0-1) to each number which are descending in order. For example;

I have a set of number:

```
    150
    152
    155
    160
    175
```

I will give those numbers a probability in this way:

for first one (150) probability is = 175/total Sum

Second one is = 160/totalsum + previous probability....and so on.

The main point is 150 will have the higher probability than others.

What would you suggest to me. Set will contain more than 30 numbers...

Here is the code:

```
int ll;
float prefitness=0;//Previous fittnesses
int minus =0;
for (int sdf=0;sdf<PopulationSize;sdf++)//population size is the total number counts
{
  ll=sortindex[sdf];//sortindex is an array with numbers in ascending order
  Sol_list[ll].fittness=(double)Sol_list[PopulationSize-1-minus].PortfolioDuration/sum+prefitness;
  prefitness=Sol_list[ll].fittness;
  minus++;
}
float move=0;
int xc;
for (int yj=0;yj<PopulationSize;yj++)
{
  xc=sortindex[yj];
  Sol_list[xc].fittnesspre =move;
  move=Sol_list[xc].fittness;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is too simple.. you parse the set once to get the sum and then you parse it the second time and create a vector with the probabilities. Or is it something else you expect as an answer ?

Comment: Yes it is simple. I have a code. Sometimes if the numbers are too close, probability values are also too close and some numbers to not obey the rule (ascending number, descending probabilities. ı donot solve the problem. Although the difference is so small, it effects the solution. Maybe it is due to rounding error or smt. the reason i am asking this simple question is to chech whether i am doing it right...thanks

Comment: If you want us to know if your existing code is right or not, then you must post your code! How can anyone help you otherwise?

Comment: We can't guess what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Sometimes I really can't imagine what the posters to this site are thinking of.

Comment: Ok. sorry. you are right, i am such an idiot:)forget to post the code I am posting it. also i am posting a sample run.

Comment: int ll;
    float prefitness=0;//previous fittnesses
 int minus =0;
      for (int sdf=0;sdf<PopulationSize;sdf++)//population size is the total number of numbers
   {
    ll=sortindex[sdf];//sortindex is the array where numbers are sorted with ascending order
    Sol_list[ll].fittness=(float)Sol_list[PopulationSize-1-minus].PortfolioDuration/sum+prefitness;
    prefitness=Sol_list[ll].fittness;
    minus++;
      }
    float move=0;
 int xc;
   for (int yj=0;yj<PopulationSize;yj++)
   {
    xc=sortindex[yj];
    Sol_list[xc].fittnesspre =move;
    move=Sol_list[xc].fittness;
   }

Comment: Instead of a comment, please edit your original post and add it as code.

Comment: Floats may not have enough significant bits to give meaningful differences. And please post your code to your question. Code in comments is terribly hard to read.

Comment: @rudy float is fine here, the code has a simple bug

Comment: @David: just back at home. I only saw the code in the comment, and wasn't able to spot anything. I see the code is in the question now. And I see the error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't using the sorted index in all access of Sol_list. This one is wrong:

```
Sol_list[PopulationSize-1-minus]
```

It should say:

```
Sol_list[sortindex[PopulationSize-1-minus]]
```

Comment: ISTM there is no need for an extra variable minus. It should be the same as sdf.